# Can't remove flux

Tags: uninstall, f.lux

I'm trying to reinstall flux and am having a hard time. `sudo apt-get remove fluxgui` returns `E: Unable to locate package fluxgui`, which makes me think it's already uninstalled. But in the software center, I see:
[image]

If I click "Remove", the machine seems to run a process for a moment and then nothing changes; the "Remove" option is still there, and I also can't open flux.

How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you install it? via the python setup / repo?

Comment: I can't remember at this point, to be honest. But I tried `pip uninstall fluxgui` as well and that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons why this might not be working.

#### 1. A manual install

In this case run the following commands to remove flux

```
cd /tmp
git clone "https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui.git"
cd xflux-gui
python download-xflux.py

# EITHER uninstall globally
sudo python setup.py install --record installed.txt
sudo xargs rm -vr < installed.txt

# EXCLUSIVE OR uinstall in your home directory
python setup.py install --user --record installed.txt
xargs rm -vr < installed.txt
```

#### 2. Missing PPA

There is a possibility that the ppa was removed after flux was installed. You can try adding the repo again and then uninstalling flux and then removing the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove fluxgui
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
sudo apt update
```

Comment: not working, seeing TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error @Rohith Yeravothula received when manually uninstalling:

```
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

It is because the current syntax is for Python 3. Use `python3` instead of `python` when running the script.